# Closed Loop Space propulsion

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, propulsion, physics, interstellar-travel, spacecraft-development

While browsing for Space propulsion found this book :

https://www.knygos.lt/lt/knygos/closed-loop-space-propulsion-new-faster-approach-2e4zy/

Closed Loop Space Propulsion New Faster Approach : The next Step in Space Travel (Paperback)
John F Roach Bse

Does anybody knows about this book and type of propulsion ?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't know anything about this book and engine specifically, but it looks a lot like the standard "make the system confusing enough that I have forgotten a key force" type of engine.  The sentence ```The geometric structure allows cancellation of unwanted forces which causes a closed system force that is futuristic in nature``` seems particularly suspect.

Comment: Stoyan, there is lots os "crazy" writing about things like engines that have magical properties.  It's total nonsense, like reading about ghosts. You're just reading a "scifi article" there, it is not reality or real.  You may enjoy ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive

Answer (score 9):

That looks like a fairly standard "I don't understand magnets"-engine, with a side order of "I don't understand conservation of momentum".  Don't spend too much time thinking about it, because it doesn't actually work.

Comment: Add a sprinkling of 'Who's Newton?' and you've got the entire dish.